# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'cache_dir "/home/celtice1/public_html/var/cache/" is not writable' in

Tags: fatal-error, zend-framework

after i upgrade to magento 2.1.3
i see this error

full Error is

can someone help me to solve this issue

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message
>   'cache_dir "/home/celtice1/public_html/var/cache/" is not writable' in
>   /home/celtice1/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/celtice1/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180):
>   Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/hom...') #1
>   /home/celtice1/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87):
>   Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/home/celtice1/...') #2
>   /home/celtice1/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153):
>   Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array) #3
>   /home/celtice1/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94):
>   Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true) #4
>   /home/celtice1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(156):
>   Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...',
>   Array, Array, true, true, true) #5 /home/celtice1/public_html/v in
>   /home/celtice1/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php
>   on line 209

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the directory?